# How to properly use the garch function in R, tseries package?

Tags: r, statistics, time-series

I am using R and I want to use the garch function from tseries package.

I have the following model:

[image]

I have historical data organised in the following way, as a matrix in R:

```
 Sigma^2_t     Sigma^2_{t-1}     epsilon^2_{t-1}
    0.223           0.190            0.131
    0.543           0.223            0.443
    0.666           0.543            0.222
      ...             ...              ...
```

This is just an example of toy data. I want to fit this using a Garch(p, q) model, where p = q = 1. I am trying to use the Garch function provided in tseries in R.

The function needs (among others) two parameters, "x" and "order". I assume "order" is c(1, 1). How, however, do I represent both vectors of data using the single "x" numerical array? I can easily represent the first two columns as

```
x = c(0.190, 0.223, 0.543, 0.666, ...).
```

However, how do I put together the residual part (epsilon) and the known volatilities (sigma) so the model returns the right coefficients?

Thank you very much,
Chicoscience

Answer (score 1):

You should just feed in your vector of observed sigma-squared values. R can do the lagging itself to figure out the lagged sigma-squared; and epsilon-squared is just a function of sigma-squared as well. So R can do all the calculations for you. As long as you've got the order right, `c(1,1)` meaning you want one sigma-squared lag term and one epsilon-squared lag term, you should be just fine.

Comment: Ok, that means then that I cannot provide my own residuals, they are calculated automatically by R. I think I had misunderstood the concept of GARCH models before and I thought I could feed my own residuals somehow (instead of using the default ones). Thanks for the insight.